# What is the policy model in RLHF for LLMs?

Tags: neural-networks, transformer, large-language-models, rlhf, decoder

What is the policy model doing explicitly in an LLM with RLHF setup?

From my understanding, LLMs generate in a way that is no different from any of their predecessors: beam search decoding, potentially with some sampling.

Does this mean the policy model is specifying how to generate the next token?